# primefaces layout

Tags: javascript, jsf, web-applications, layout, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.4.2 with JSF2.1 I created a page divided into some layout units. In right layout unit I have a accordionPanel and created dynamic menu, and middle center layout consist of ui:include and a page is loaded in the layer , When I click on a link opens a dialog That includes a dynamic page.
After opening and closing the dialog without performing any action in right layout,middle center layout doesn't work anymore. I can see it,but I click input text I can not type anything into it also click other components nothing happens!!! what is problem?Is there a solution to this?

when click menu items open dialog include other page and when click tree node center layout change,the page that open in dialog work well,but when close dialog ,center layout buttons and inputs dont work,other layouts components work well!

my new code:

```
     <p:layoutUnit id="right" position="east" size="145"  style="text-align:center;direction: ltr!important;padding: 0px!important;">
                    <h:form prependId="false">
                         <script type="text/javascript">
                            function test(id,url,title){
                                document.getElementById('h1').value=id;
                                document.getElementById('h2').value=url;
                                document.getElementById('h3').value=title;
                                salamm.jq.click();
                            } 
                        </script>
                        <h:inputHidden id="h1" value="#{adminC.nclose}" />
                        <h:inputHidden id="h2" value="#{adminC.nurl}"/>
                        <h:inputHidden id="h3" value="#{adminC.ntitle}"/>
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{adminC.addTab()}" id="salam" widgetVar="salamm" update=":dlgpanel" onstart="waitDialogmain.show()" style="display: none" oncomplete="waitDialogmain.hide();dlg1.show()"/>  
                        <p:accordionPanel style="text-align: center;font-family: tahoma!important" activeIndex="#{menuGen.activeIndex}">
                             <p:tab title="connections"  id="t0" rendered="#{menuGen.menuList1.length()>0}"  >

                                 <center>

                                                <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{menuGen.menuList1}"/>
                                            </center>
                                            <br/>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="manage" id="t1" rendered="#{menuGen.menuList2.length()>0}" >
                                            <center>
                                                <h:outputText value="#{menuGen.menuList2}" escape="false"/>
                                            </center>
                                            <br/>
                                        </p:tab>

                            </p:accordionPanel>
                     </h:form>
                                 </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit id="center" style="padding: 0px!important;" position="center">
                    <p:layout widgetVar="mkh">
                        <p:layoutUnit id="middleright" position="east" size="170"  collapsible="true" style="padding: 0px;direction: ltr" >
                            <h:form prependId="false">
                             <p:tree value="#{treeC.root}"  var="node" dynamic="true" style="width: 165px;border: none;direction: rtl!important;text-align: right;font-family: tahoma;font-weight: bold" selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeC.selectedNode}">
                                 <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeC.onNodeSelect}" onstart="waitDialogmain.show()" oncomplete="waitDialogmain.hide()" />       
                                 <p:treeNode  >
                                     <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
                                 </p:treeNode>

                             </p:tree>
                             <p:commandButton onclick="mkh.toggle('east')" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-e" title="ctr+shift+right arrow" style="width: 6px;height: 80px;position: absolute;top: 50%;" type="button"/> 
                      </h:form>
                        </p:layoutUnit>
                        <p:layoutUnit id="middlecenter" style="padding: 0px!important;" position="center">
                            <p:layout style="text-align: center">
                                <p:layoutUnit id="middlecenter1" style="padding: 0px!important;" position="center" resizable="true" >

                                        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" id="dlgpanelcenter">                 
                                        <center>
                                            <ui:include src="./../users/networkReport.xhtml" />
                                        </center>
                                    </p:outputPanel>

                                </p:layoutUnit>                                
                                <p:layoutUnit id="middleBottom" size="100"  style=" padding: 0px!important" position="south" resizable="true" >



                                </p:layoutUnit>
                            </p:layout>
                        </p:layoutUnit>
                    </p:layout>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
            <p:dialog id="dlg" resizable="false" maximizable="true" modal="true"  draggable="true" height="400"  widgetVar="dlg1" style="background-color: white!important;text-align: center!important;direction: ltr">

                <p:outputPanel style="direction: rtl" id="dlgpanel" >                   
                    <center>
                        <ui:include  src="#{adminC.url}" />
                    </center>
                   </p:outputPanel>

            </p:dialog>

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

and this is one page that open inside dialog :

```
 <ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            template="./../template/masterTemplate.xhtml"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

<ui:define name="top">

</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="regChannel" prependId="false" style="text-align: right;float: none!important">
      ........

   </h:form>        
</ui:define>
<ui:define name="bottom">

</ui:define>
```

Comment: Probably you're dealing a javascript error. Open a browser developer tool like firebug and look if there is an issue.

Comment: i checked with chrome debugger but not problem!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: @faranak,  are you sure you need all those `<ui:define` in your dialog ? try to remove all the `<ui:define` + `template="./../template/masterTemplate.xhtml"` from inside `ui:composition` and just leave the `<ui:composition....<h:form...</h:form></ui:composition> `

Comment: thanks,i do it but dont solve my problem:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of all your nested forms (`<h:form`),

I noticed you got many of them

You can't have the following structure on page

```
<h:form.....
  some elements....
  some elements....
  some elements....
  <h:form....
```

For example you can place one `<h:form` that will wrap `<p:tab`

Or place `<h:form` inside each `<p:tab`

Another way to check that you don't have nested `<h:form` is to do *view source* in your page and look if you have `<form` inside `<form` (nested forms which is baaaad)

---

**Update**

Are you sure you need all those `<ui:define` in your dialog ? try to remove all the `<ui:define` + `template="./../template/masterTemplate.xhtml"` from inside `ui:composition` and just leave the

```
<ui:composition....
    <h:form...

    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I got rid of all forms. And page that opens in  dialoge have only one <h:form> , but did not resolve my issue!! and when just use one h:form in page that include layouts , at initialization layouts component Error occurs and not rendered page ! so I had put a <h:form> tag  for each layerunit!

Comment: I didn't tell you to get rid of all forms and leave only one form... just to get rid of the nested forms... you can post your new code... but before that just make sure you don't have commandButtons outside the form...

Comment: I realized, I did it just to test, I did not think the problem of the form tags,ok ,I'll post my new code

Comment: tip: make sure that you have `h:form` inside `<p:dialog` and not the other way ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14051661/617373

Comment: This dialog contains a <ui:include  src="#{adminC.url}" /> tag when click menu items, open page inside dialog that this page have <h:form>

Comment: Thank you Daniel. The problem was solved by removing <ui:define> . But my manage bean scope was viewScoped,That caused my buttons dont work and I thought my issue is still not resolved,change mainManageBean scope to sessionScoped and solved my issue,thanks again